# Gitlab sync repository masters with folder?

Tags: git, gitlab, repository, gitlab-ci

I use Gitlab CE. Now I want to have a folder (e.g. /home/user/repositoryMaster), which contains all of the repository master files and folders.

For example:

repositoryMaster contains:

- Repository1

  - src
  - README.md
  - ...
- Repository2

  - src
  - documentation
  - README.md
  - ...

This directories and files should be read only and should automatically synchronize with the Gitlab server. (When I push a file, it should also appear in the folder)